# Does the following relation of cartesian product, Hom and tensor product hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I am reading the book *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra* by Siegfried Bosch. In $\mathrm{p}. 298$, it says that from the universal property of fiber product we have the equality $$(X\times_SY)(T)=X(T)\times Y(T),$$
where $X$, $Y$ and $T$ are $S$-schemes. Namely,
$$\mathrm{Hom}_S(T, X\times_S Y)=\mathrm{Hom}_S(T, X)\times\mathrm{Hom}_S(T, Y),$$
since $X(T)$ is defined to be $\mathrm{Hom}_S(T, X).$

I have known the following tow things:

1. fiber product of two affine schemes is an affine scheme again as it is the spectrum of a tensor product;
2. there is a bijection between $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Spec}\:B, \mathrm{Spec}\:A)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B)$ (for convention it is denoted by $\varphi$, we shall use it later).

From my understanding $S$-schemes correspond to actions on rings. So we may take $S=\mathrm{Spec}\:\{0\}, T=\mathrm{Spec}\:R, X=\mathrm{Spec}\:A$ and $Y=\mathrm{Spec}\:B$ which leads to two questions:

1. In algebraic language do we have $\mathrm{Hom}(R, A\otimes_R B)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(R,A)\times\mathrm{Hom}(R, B)$ as groups?
2. More generally, do we have $\mathrm{Hom}_{R'}(R, A\otimes_{R'} B)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{R'}(R,A)\times\mathrm{Hom}_{R'}(R, B)$ as $R$-algebras if we take $S=\mathrm{Spec}\:R'$?

Unfortunately, I have found a counter example for the above questions. We can take $R'=R=A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have a contradiction $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. As far as I am concerned there may be two things went wrong:

- $S$-schemes do not correspond to actions on rings i.e. we cannot get $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A, B)$ from $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Spec}\:R}(\mathrm{Spec}\:B,\mathrm{Spec}\:A)$;
- The bijection $\varphi$ (mentioned above) is only between sets. We can not pass it to group homomorphisms.

Could anyone help me find what is going wrong and give some explanations?

Comment: In addition to the issue pointed out in the answer below, you're using *module* Hom instead of *algebra* Hom in your (fake) counterexample.

Comment: @KReiser I am considering $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. Doesn't the algebra Hom coincide with the module Hom?

Comment: Not even close. There's only one map of rings (aka $\Bbb Z$-algebras) from $\Bbb Z$ to any other ring: the map that sends $1\mapsto 1$.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. That really makes sense. We require this condition in ring homomorphisms but here 1 is also a generator of additive group.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that $\operatorname{Spec}$ is contravariant, so it sends coproducts to products. This means the tensor products of commutative algebras is not a product but a coproduct, and the correct formula is $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R′}(A⊗_{R′}B,R)≅\operatorname{Hom}_{R′}(A,R)×\operatorname{Hom}_{R′}(B,R).$$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! When is Hom(A,B) isomorphic to Hom(B,A)?

Comment: Basically never, unless there is a coincidence. Of course it happens when $A=B$, otherwise it has no reason to.